# Multiplying a variable without recalling it - PHP

Tags: php

I feel very stupid currently because I cannot find this, and for the life of me I cannot remember how to do it correctly.

```
$a = $a * .95;
```

I think what I'm trying to do is this:

```
$a *= .95;
```

If someone could verify that I'm correct, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What do you mean by 'recalling'? The second option you posted does the multiplication and assigns the result back to `$a`, yes..

Comment: here you go you can verify here. http://codepad.org/VXBxgM0Y

Comment: Thank you Icedwater, that is what I was wanting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are valid so if you don't want to "recall" the variable, use the second one:

```
$a *= .95;
```